# Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to combine the price with " USD" but I am getting this error.

"Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax."

```
IsNull(pe.SalePrice,pe.ProductPrice) + ' USD' AS price
```

Comment: my apologies, I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to cast the `money` value to string. At the moment you are getting an implicit cast the other way round according to the [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) rules (i.e. it is trying to do `CAST('USD' AS MONEY)` then add the result to the sum which will fail as that is not a number)

```
SELECT 
   CAST(IsNull(pe.SalePrice,pe.ProductPrice) AS VARCHAR(30)) + ' USD' AS price
```

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT(IsNull(pe.SalePrice,pe.ProductPrice), ' USD') AS price

I am not sure about the IsNull part

Comment: perhaps I have the wrong tag for my question but I tried this and got CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: Ahhh, SQL Server.  I didn't see that.  You Will have to cast it and the to add them you just do as you are doing, with the plus sign.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: SQL Server Denali will have a `CONCAT` function that will take care of the casting automatically.